# Loading some tables of an innodb databse into memory in mariadb

Tags: mysql, caching, memory, mariadb, innodb

I have a innoDB database with size of about 40GB.
The text-only tables overall have around 10MB and the rest of the size belong to blobs.
Is it better to load the text-only tables into the memory at startup.
If it is useful how can I do it?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Putting anything into memory competes with InnoDB's favorite way of caching data -- the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Bottom line:  You *might* get some improvement.  But don't bother going to the extra effort.